# How to pass class name dynamically in to class tag in Testng XML

Tags: java, xml, selenium, testng

I need to pass the class name dynamically in to `<Class>` in Testng XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
      <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"></parameter>
    <classes>
      <class name="testCaseWithKeywordFramework.TestCase1_Login"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->

</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

in the above XML code i want to pass the class name dynamically, can anyone help me in this.

Comment: I did not get it.  Why do you wanna pass it dynamically ? Or you mean you want to use class  programmatically which should be generated from code?

Comment: you mean you want to use class programmatically..

Comment: I want to use class name programmatically

Comment: for that you have to create testNG xml programmatically.Did you create it?

Comment: No Sir, actually i didn't have any idea on creating testNG xml programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke TestNG from your own programs very easily:

```
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { Run2.class });
testng.addListener(tla);
testng.run();
```

This example creates a TestNG object and runs the test class Run2.

For more you can refer [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically)

Similarly, you can invoke TestNG on a testng.xml file or you can create a virtual testng.xml file yourself

For example, suppose you want to create the following virtual file:

```
<suite name="TmpSuite" >
  <test name="TmpTest" >
    <classes>
      <class name="test.failures.Child"  />
    <classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

You would use the following code:

```
XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
suite.setName("TmpSuite");
XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
test.setName("TmpTest");
List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
classes.add(new XmlClass("test.failures.Child"));
test.setXmlClasses(classes) ;
```

And then you can pass this XmlSuite to TestNG:

```
List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
suites.add(suite);
TestNG tng = new TestNG();
tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
tng.run();
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this is  very useful i will refer it and if i able to understood.. i will accept your  for sure.

Comment: @SatishRongala : No problem bud. try it out.

Comment: i have one doubt sir. after using the above code.. i have to run the testNG XML or i can directly run the class that i am using?

Comment: testng.xml will be created by running your code. So no need to run testng.xml manually , directly running the class would do the job I believe.

Comment: really Thank you so much sir.. now itself i will try your code :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by creating the suite file itself at run time. Check this example - http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-creating-testng-suite-xml-from-spreadsheet/

Comment: Thank you for your information provided.. you understood that what i am searching for.. but i will wait for some other information.. if anyone can explain it.. or else i will accept your answer.

Comment: i have one doubt sir. after using the above code.. i have to run the testNG XML or i can directly run the class that i am using?